# Turning php to very strict

Tags: php, apache, appfog

I would like to configure my environment (php.ini and apache) to be as strict as possible.
for example:

Given a class in path `c:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\My.Class.php`

I would like that

```
include('\classes\my.class.php');
```

**to fail.** *(even on windows)*

And I would like that

```
include('./classes/My.Class.php');
```

**to joy.** *case sensitive*

The main reason is that appfog is strict with paths, does not allow backslash in it and is case sensitive.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible using includes. Since slashes work fine on Windows, I don't see any reason to ever use backslashes in paths.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I post this question I found it out of my knowledge and easy to answer. I solved my problem editing all the code and respect the case (being case sensitive), turning the forward slash to back (as they should be from day 1) and inserting a dot in the beggining of the path.

Comment: What would prevent this from happening to begginers (like me) that receive a lot of errors and warnings from PaaS (APPFOG in my case) is some configuration in apache like:
`ALLOW_FORWARD_SLASH = FALSE`
`PATH_LINKS_CASE_SENSITIVE = TRUE`
`DOT_TO_START_A_PATH = TRUE`

Comment: Perhaps you could suggest this as a feature on the PHP bug tracker: https://bugs.php.net/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using includes, perhaps make an autoloader that uses all of your rules.

Then you can control how the files are included.

Comment: I'm using my own autoloader (not so good for sure) the main problem is that after months developing i spent a full week amending my code to deploy on appfog.It broked everywhere. I surely would like to develop stricter from now on.